# Running Ionic3 in WKWebView in a different port

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview

According to https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/, the ionic apps are now hosted on a wkwebview, in http://localhost:8080

I need to host it (don't ask why, but is something I cannot change) on port 3000. Is that possible/configurable somewhere?

Comment: You mean that you want to host it on mobile on port 3000?

Comment: yes. Basically is because the auth url redirects back to localhost:3000 in the inappbrowser and I don't want that to trigger a page load error. and I cannot change the redirection_uri

Comment: Can you please give some more details on what exactly you are trying to do? WKWebView is only used on iOS, so even if you get the redirect working, it most likely will not work on Android. Couldn't you do the same with deeplinking using an app/url-scheme?

Answer (score 1):

You could fork the ionic WKWebView plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and change every instance of port 8080 to port 3000 in the source code.

Then in your ionic project use `ionic cordova add <path to your forked plugin repo>` to install the forked plugin.